# В Cordova Local-Notification не работает every: "week"

Tags: cordova

Мне нужно, чтобы уведомления отправлялись каждую неделю, сам плагин работает, уведомления отправляются, пока //every : "week", но, если "//" убрать, то уведомление просто не отправляется.

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
                    id: 1,
                    title: "Message Title",
                    message: "Message Text",
                    firstAt: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 500),
                    every: 25,
                    sound: true
                });
```

Comment: Для отправки по интервалу разве не конструкция `trigger: { every: 'week', count: 5 }` используется?

Comment: Его я тоже пробовал, тоже не работает